# Reset Netgear WNDR4300 to factory from DDWRT

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I flashed DDWRT as I was going to use WallWatcher & analyze packets etc etc -- well now I have no need for this so I want to flash it back to factory.  I downloaded firmware 1.02.78 from [enter link description here](http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/product/WNDR4300#searchResults) but what are the proper steps so I do not brick my router?

EDIT ......

I followed the tutorial found here: 
[Flash back to stock](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=79802&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0)

and now my router about every minute will rebboot itself, but for the most part the power light is a steady amber.  Is this part of the process or did something get mucked up in the process?

Comment: The stock firmware is already OpenWrt.  So all you need to do is upload the firmware you want to use using the proper procedure you used for the modified firmware.  The support page for this router on the DDWRT website describes the process.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the doco describing how?  I have googled and unable to find it (why I posted here)

Comment: You should follow the same procedure you originally followed.  [This](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR4000) isn't the exact model but close enough to get the idea how to perform the reset procedure properly.

Comment: So the downgrade process is the exact same as the upgrade process (step wise)?

Comment: There is tons of information which you should read, on the DD-WRT website, but the Wikipedia page for the WNDR4000 is accurate enough since the WNDR4300 is its "successor"